# ifttt: redirect message (text, photo and video) from telegram to email

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, ifttt

There is an [applet](https://ifttt.com/applets/e8zfUP2q-send-email-and-some-text-to-ifttt-on-telegram-to-email-a-friend-using-gmail) which allows to send text messages from telegram to some email. Unfortunately there is a limitation: it only works with text.

I would like to have the same functionality, but for images, video and may be audio. I suppose media content should be attached to the email.

Is there a tool for this task? If no, what is the easiest way to implement it?

Comment: Write a little more about your task. What are user actions? How do they specify respective email addresses?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I have a telegram channel and I want to subscribe some non-telegram users to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need split this idea to a few and search for each of following topics:

- echo bot using `python-telegram-bot`
- `python-telegram-bot` and Telegram object types (photo, video, etc.)
- how to send email using python and SMTP
- how to add attachments email using python

After that you'll be able to understand what else is missing.

Comment: @doubts let me know if that works for you or you need more details